# AWS S3 - Store User Profiles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm setting up a simple static web site on S3 for our community. Users enter basic info (no credentials are created). I would want this info to be appended to a file (preferably json) to use it to send out reminders, invites, etc. Is this possible in S3 or I need to buy an EC2 instance? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a storage service. It sounds like you need to use one of the AWS compute services: EC2, ECS or Lambda.

Comment: But reading from AWS documentation, JavaScript is allowed. So was wondering if I could write to a log file in the S3 bucket.

Comment: @Kutuhalam among the issues, here: S3 deals in atomic object write operations against entire objects. It has no "append."

Comment: You can write to S3 using JavaScript that is running somewhere other than S3, like in the browser. You can't run code that does things like send out reminders, invites, etc. directly on S3. You would need a compute service for that.

Answer (score 0):

As Mark pointed out you will have to use EC2, ECS or Lambda, you can use any of the above mentioned platforms and alongside you could use [Aws Cloudfront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html#AccessLogsOverview) for logging and pushing purposes into s3 or any other.